# Circular Queue in C for an embedded project

Tags: c, queue, circular-list, embedded

I wrote a simple circular queue. (in order to store characters because of the fact, that I am using UART through the DMA and sometimes my printf's override each other)
I am looking for some review, though my testfile was successful I have the feeling I've overseen something and the queue might be buggy at some point.
I appreciate any kind of critics, ideas or improvements

Header File:

```
#ifndef __QUEUEH
#define __QUEUEH

typedef struct queue {

    unsigned int head;
    unsigned int tail;
    unsigned char* buf;
    unsigned int bufSize;
    unsigned int freeSpace;
    unsigned int occuSpace;
    unsigned char initialized;

} queue_t;

extern int queue_init(queue_t* q, unsigned char* buf, unsigned int bufSize);
extern int enqueue(queue_t* q, unsigned char* element, unsigned int size);
extern int dequeue(queue_t* q, unsigned char* str, int strMaxSize);
// change to static
extern int printQueue(queue_t* q);
#endif
```

C-File:

```
#include "queue.h"
#if !defined bool
typedef unsigned char bool;
#endif

extern int queue_init(queue_t* q, unsigned char* buf, unsigned int bufSize) {
    q->head = -1;
    q->tail = 0;
    q->buf = buf;
    q->bufSize = bufSize;
    q->freeSpace = bufSize;
    q->occuSpace = 0;
    q->initialized = 1;
    return 0;
}

static inline bool moveTail(queue_t* q) {
    q->occuSpace = q->occuSpace - 2 - (q->buf)[q->tail];
    q->freeSpace = q->freeSpace + 2 + (q->buf)[q->tail];
    q->tail = (q->tail + (q->buf)[q->tail]+2) % (q->bufSize);
    return 0;
}

static inline bool enoughSpaceAvailable(queue_t* q, unsigned int size) {
    if(q->freeSpace < size+2)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

extern int enqueue(queue_t* q, unsigned char* element, unsigned int size) {

    if(size==0)
        return -5;
    else if(size>q->bufSize-2)
        return -8;

    while(!enoughSpaceAvailable(q,size))
            moveTail(q);

    q->occuSpace = q->occuSpace + 2 + size;
    q->freeSpace = q->freeSpace - 2 - size;
    q->head = (q->head+1)%(q->bufSize);
    (q->buf)[q->head] = size;
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        q->head = (q->head+1)%(q->bufSize);
        (q->buf)[q->head] = element[i];
    }
    q->head = (q->head+1)%(q->bufSize);
    (q->buf)[q->head] = size;
    return 0;
}

extern int dequeue(queue_t* q, unsigned char* str, int strMaxSize) {

    int len = q->buf[q->tail];
    if(q->freeSpace == q->bufSize) return -6; else if(strMaxSize<len) return -7;

    for(int j=0; j<len; j++) {
        str[j] = q->buf[(q->tail+1+j)%(q->bufSize)];
    }
    moveTail(q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the comment "change to static".

Comment: I put it there to indicate, that the print function wasnt meant to be an extern function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Redundant bytes

What's confusing about your implementation is that you are using two extra bytes for each element enqueued, but those bytes are redundant.  You are adding a `size` byte both before and after each element, but only the "before" byte is ever used.  You should remove the "after" byte because it serves no purpose.

#### Size byte is not large enough

You only reserve room for a single byte to indicate the size of the element.  However, your `enqueue()` function takes `unsigned int size` as its argument.  Therefore, if `size` is greater than 255, your program will encode the incorrect value in the size byte and things will fail after that.  Either you should leave room for `sizeof(unsigned int)` bytes to encode the size, or you should limit the `size` argument to an `unsigned char` if you expect to only enqueue data smaller than 256 bytes.

#### Miscellaneous

- The field `occuSpace` is set but never used.  You should remove that field, because you can always compute the value as `bufSize - freeSpace` anyways.
- The field `initialized` is set but never used.  It should either be removed, or you should check it in all your functions and return an error if the queue is not initialized.
- Instead of returning `-5`, `-8`, and `-7` as error codes, you should define some error codes in your header and return them instead of hardcoded numbers.
- Some functions such as `queue_init()` and `moveTail()` can't fail and always return 0.  You should either make those functions return `void` since they can't fail, or modify them to check for error conditions and possibly return an error code.  For example, in `queue_init()`, you could check for these errors:

  - `q == NULL`
  - `buf == NULL`
  - `bufSize == 0`
- Instead of:

> ```
> #if !defined bool
> typedef unsigned char bool;
> #endif
> ```

just do

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

You should also use `false` and `true` instead of `0` and `1`, for the functions that return `bool`.

Comment: In order to confirm:
The size byte after each element was useless.
I added a second size byte at the beginning, so now I can add strings with the maximum length of two bytes.
Occupied space was useless.
And your other recommendations I implemented too.

Comment: @OliverAl-Hassani yes that is all correct.

Answer (score 5):

**Functionality unclear**

Post discusses "... circular queue. (in order to store characters ...".

After digging deeply into code I now realize the goal is not to enqueue a character and then a character and so on.  Instead the goal is to enqueue a group of characters, then another group and so on.

This is not clear from the the post and importantly, it is **not clear from the .h file**.

**Documentation**

The .h file, as a public interface deserves  as least a little documentation/comment per function.

**Nonuniform name-space**

`__QUEUEH, queue, queue_init, enqueue, dequeue, printQueue` would benefit with a more  common naming convention to clearly show that they belong together.

Consider `QUEUE_H, queue, queue_init, queue_set, queue_get, queue_print`

**`queue_t`**

[Information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding): The members of `queue_t` do not need to be in the .h file.  The below is sufficient.  If external code needs to read any of these members, I recommend a function to do so.

```
typedef struct queue queue_t;
```

Put the full `struct queue` definition in the .c file.

`.initialized` is a good candidate for `bool`.

```
// unsigned char initialized;
bool initialized;
```

**Unnecessary item in .h**

As a [`static`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211198/circular-queue-in-c-for-an-embedded-project?noredirect=1#comment408450_211198) function, `printQueue` does not belong in the .h file.  Remove it.

---

**Avoid standard library collisions**

The below conflicts with `bool` from `stdbool.h`.  Do not re-invent the standard boolean type.

```
// #if !defined bool
// typedef unsigned char bool;
// #endif
#include <stdbool.h>
```

**`queue_init()`**

Why set `.head`, an unsigned type, to a negative value?  Set to a unsigned value.

```
// q->head = -1;
q->head = -1u;
```

**`moveTail()`**

The role of magic number 2 is unclear here and in many of the functions.  Explain the `2`.

**Unexpected `strMaxSize`**

How does reading the data in the queue relate to the length of anything?

```
int len = q->buf[q->tail];
```

The role of `strMaxSize` in `dequeue()` is unclear.

**Hmmmmm**

After more review it *looks* like the first character in a group of characters is the group's length.

**`enoughSpaceAvailable()`**

Avoid overflow: `size+2` can overflow - this code has no control over the value of `size`.  Consider a more robust test.

```
// if(q->freeSpace < size+2) return 0;
//return 1;

return q->freeSpace > size && q->freeSpace - size >= 2;
```

**const**

Many functions would benefit with a `const queue_t *`

```
// enoughSpaceAvailable(queue_t* q, unsigned int size)
enoughSpaceAvailable(const queue_t* q, unsigned int size)
```

**3 to do the job of 2**

Unclear why code uses `.bufSize, .freeSpace, .occuSpace` when only 2 are needed.  I'd expect `.bufSize, .occuSpace` are sufficient here.

---

**Overall**

Code lacks documentation to indicate the overall coding goals.  Without that, there is too much to discover.

I still do not know how to use best these calls.  Will `enqueue(q, "", 0);` cause havoc?   How to test is the queue is empty? What are all the error codes?  Why are errors negative?  What does a positive response mean?

To me, it is  the un-posted testfile contains too much information there and not enough here.

This code deserves an update and then a following review.

---

Sample alternate `aqueue.h`.
I avoided "queue" as too generic and used "aqueue".

```
/*
 * aqueue: queue of groups of binary data
 */

#ifndef AQUEUE_H
#define AQUEUE_H

typedef struct aqueue aqueue_t;

// All functions that return `int` return 0 on success.

/*
 * Initialize the queue with the buffer to use and its size.
 * Size [4..UINT_MAX]
 * Return TBD with invalid parameter values.
 */
int aqueue_init(aqueue_t* q, unsigned char* buf, unsigned bufSize);

/*
 * Insert a copy of what `data` points to.
 * Return TBD with insufficient space
 */
int queue_set(aqueue_t* q, const unsigned char* data, unsigned dataSize);

/*
 * Extract entry from the queue.
 * Return TBD when attempted with empty queue.
 * Return TBD when dataSize is too small.
 */
int aqueue_get(aqueue_t* q, unsigned char *data, unsigned dataSize);

/*
 * Queue empty?
 */
_Bool aqueue_empty(const aqueue_t* q);

/*
 * Get data without removing from the queue  (Peek)
 * Return TBD when attempted with empty queue.
 * Return TBD when dataSize is too small.
 */
int aqueue_top(const aqueue_t* q, unsigned char* data, unsigned dataSize);

#endif
```

Comment: The calling code likely needs to know the size of `queue_t` thwarting my `information hiding` suggestion.  If so, leave the full declaration of `queue_t` in the.h file.

Comment: You understood/interpreted the functionality of my queue correctly: The queue shall store strings, whereby the idea was to store before every string respectively its length. queue_enqueue(&q, (unsigned char*)"", 0) results into a caught error in the updated code. (enqueue returns then only the enum value QUEUE_PARAM_BUFFERSIZE_TOOSMALL). Queue_enqueue(&q, (unsigned char*)"", 1) worked fine, I think because "" is a temporary string which only contains the string terminal symbol '\0'.
I chose negative error codes arbitrarily (updated to enum)
I will post the updated code.

Comment: yes I had to leave the complete declaration of queue_t within the header file, otherwise it caused:
"Application/main.c:52:10: error: storage size of 'q' isn't known."

Comment: @Oliver Al-Hassani I see the need for `queue_t` within the header file as a design weakness.  It implies that the unposted calling code (`main()`) is doing things it should not.  A better `queue_...` would hide the inner details from the calling code.  Think of `FILE` as in `fopen(), fgetc(), fprintf(), fclose()`.  What do we know of its size, or members - very little.  That is how your `queue_...` should be too.

Comment: I did some research within my debian kernel files for the example FILE in fprintf. I found the definition of FILE in stdio.h: typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE;
And __IO_FILE is from libio.h with its complete structure content, visible within the header file:
struct _IO_FILE { ... }.
you can also relate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424349/where-to-find-struct-io-file
So linux kernel code also has user structures visible in the header files.

Comment: @OliverAl-Hassani The member of `FILE` though are not needed to use the standard `FILE` functions.  There is no need for `FILE f`, just `FILE *f`.  Any access to `FILE` members is a matter of performance (in-lining code) vs. a function call.  Code as you like, yet I find abstracted helper code, like this `queue` could be, to have more long term value when coded and used in a manner that separates the members from the caller.

Comment: I thought about it again, and as you say it would be possible to make the queue struct as described in the from the OP accepted answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672015/hiding-members-in-a-c-struct. 
Despite, one would need to use either malloc, or one has to force the user again to create a buffer for the queue_t.
For me personally it's getting more complicated than pragmatic.

Comment: (by the way I don't want to use malloc)

Comment: @OliverAl-Hassani Consider the trade-off of "it's getting more complicated than pragmatic".  It is usually more valuable and pragmatic to minimize the complication of the calling code, even if that makes this `queue` code more complex.  There are various ways to handle  the difficultly in memory management, but in the end, the idea is to make it easy from the caller-point-of-view - regardless of which way you choose to manage memory.  Perhaps knowing more why your application needs to avoid `malloc()` would help - yet that is getting beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: @OliverAl-Hassani Example code where the caller, unknowing provides memory with a _compound literal_: [printf converter to print in binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641674/2410359).  In your case code can use `queue *q = &(unsigned char [queue_n()]){ 0}`, perhaps wrapped in a macro.  Various approaches.

Comment: until yesterday I wasn't aware, that arm-none-eabi-gcc provides a stdlib and further. I've just implemented a handler and encapsulated the queue_t and now it just looks beautiful!!!

Comment: Excellent review. Regarding the `bool` remark, the reason might be to allow C90 compatibility, as often required because of dusty old embedded system compilers. The correct way to do it would however rather be `#ifndef __STDC_VERSION__ typedef unsigned char bool; #define false 0 #define true 1 #else #include <stdbool.h> #endif`. But then of course this doesn't give true booleans. Given `bool b = 2;`, C90 fake boolean will get value 2, whereas standard C boolean will get value 1.

Comment: @Lundin True that a define test is warranted yet since `_Bool` came in with [C99](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1608350/2410359) and not C89, the test would need to be more than just testing `__STDC_VERSION__`.

Comment: Ah crap, you are right. `__STDC_VERSION__` was introduced in C95, not C90. Looking at my actual production code doing stuff like this, it goes: `#ifdef __STDC_VERSION__  #if (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L)     #include <stdint.h> #include <stdbool.h>` ... `#else /* manual typedefs */`.

Comment: @Lundin [How to find my current compiler's standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4991754/2410359) is a good resource.